# RSpec in pure Ruby uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, rspec

In my pure ruby 2.7 app I'm getting an error `NameError: uninitialized constant LogParser`.

LogParser class is located in `app/lib/log_parser.rb` what am I missing?

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

RSpec.describe LogParser do
  subject { LogParser.new(path) }
  let(:path) { 'spec/fixtrues/sample.log' }

  describe '.parse' do
    context 'when filepath was provided' do
      let(:file_instance) { instance_double(File) }

      before do
        allow(File).to receive(:new) { file_instance }
        # allow(file_instance).to receive(:open).with(path)
      end

      it 'expect to receive file path' do
        subject.parse
        expect(file_instance).should_receive(path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

`.rspec`

```
--require spec_helper
```

Comment: require log_parser.rb file in  your spec

Comment: You're right, thanks!